# is there any way to invoke google home or voice assistant automatically using scheduled database input or using a google action?

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home

I want to set a reminder using google calendar and want to trigger the google home without invoking google home using voice. Is it possible to integrate with a database for scheduling tasks or using a google action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not... quite...

Although you can send [Daily Updates](https://developers.google.com/assistant/engagement/daily) or one-time scheduled [Notifications](https://developers.google.com/assistant/engagement/notifications) through your Action, these will not go to Smart Speakers - primarily they will show up as notifications on a mobile device.